# Can I write my own shaders in meshlab.? Seems i can only use existing defined ones

Tags: meshlab

Does Meshlab allow you to write your own shaders? Currently, i can only seem to access pre-written ones like Cook-Torrance.gdp etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your .gdp, .vert and .frag files and copy them to the "shaders" directory. Next time you launch meshlab the will be available there.

If you need help with the .gdp file, just copy one of them (for example glass.gdp) and change the lines where *VertexProgram="glass.vert"* and 
*FragmentProgram="glass.frag"* are defined.